# Wondering why this animated svg behaves differently in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7694232/test.svg 
Looks like this animated svg works in firefox and opera as i planned it (green blob is hiding and showing with 1s pause for both actions) while in google chrome it does one cycle and stays in the same configuration for the rest of the animation. I'm just wondering am i doing something wrong and svg animate code could be rewritten to work correctly even in chrome or is it just a problem of browser itself?

Comment: I think that Chrome is currently fundamentally broken with respect to SVG/SMIL animation. For example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093315/why-does-this-js-created-svg-animation-not-work-in-chrome).