# Why does this JS-created SVG <animate> not work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, smil

Consider this simple SVG SMIL animation:

```svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
  <circle r="40" fill="red">
    <animate
      attributeType="CSS" begin="click"
      attributeName="fill" to="blue" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

This works correctly in Chrome v18 on Windows (modulo a bug with holding the color):
http://phrogz.net/svg/change-color-on-click-simple.svg

When I generate the `<animate>` element using JavaScript, all works well in Firefox, Safari, and Opera, but not Chrome. In Chrome, nothing happens when I click on the circle.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
  <circle r="40" fill="red"/>
  <script>
    var c = document.querySelector('circle');
    createOn(c,'animate',{
      attributeType:'CSS', begin:'click',
      attributeName:'fill', to:'blue',
      dur:'0.3s', fill:'freeze'
    });
    function createOn(el,name,attrs){
      var e = el.appendChild(document.createElementNS(el.namespaceURI,name));
      for (var name in attrs) e.setAttribute(name,attrs[name]);
      return e;
    }
  </script>
```

See this JavaScript version here:
http://phrogz.net/svg/change-color-on-click-simple-js.svg

There are no script errors in the console. The content of the first example was actually generated by choosing Copy As HTML from the Chrome Developer Tools after loading the second example, so I know that it is producing the correct attribute names and values. The `namespaceURI` of the `<animate>` element is the same between both (the SVG namespace), as is the `namespaceURI` of all attributes (`null`).

Is there a way to get JS-generated `<animate>` elements to work in Chrome?

Comment: I have logged this as a Chromium bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122846

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I define the attributes **before** appending the animation, it appears to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/VFUHk/

Comment: Whoa! Excellent find. I suppose this is not entirely insane, then.